# Why <form:errors> tag not showing the Error Messages inside <form:form> tag of Spring?

Tags: java, spring

`<form:errors>` tag not showing Error Messages when I put it inside the `<form:form>` tag of Spring.

It shows Error Messages, If the `<form:errors>` tag is out of the `<form:form>` tag. I have printed the errors of the binding result and it shows the errors as below:

```
[Field error in object 'student1' on field 'lastname': rejected value []; codes [Size.student1.lastname,Size.lastname,Size.java.lang.String,Size]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [student1.lastname,lastname]; arguments []; default message [lastname],16,6]; default message [Size.student1.**lastname**]]
```

Note: If I place `<form:errors>`  inside the `<form:form>` tag it is not working.

Here is the JSP code:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact Manager</title>
    <style>
        .errStyle{
        color:red;}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<h2>${headerName}</h2>
<!-- This line shows the error messages of input binding exception. -->
<!--<form:errors path="student1.*" cssClass="errStyle"/> this line shows the error messages-->
<form:form method="post" action="/SampleTutorials/student/addBean.html">

      <label>Last Names</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname"/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Last Names</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname"/>
         <form:errors path="student1.lastname"> </form:errors>
        </td>
    </tr><!--**** Here it doesnt shows the error message -->
    <tr>
        <td><label>DOB</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dob"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Email</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Telephone</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="telephone"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Skillset</label></td>
        <td>
            <select multiple name="skillSet">
              <option value="J2EE">J2EE</option>
              <option value="J2SE">J2SE</option>
              <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
              <option value="Hibernate">Hibernate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Flat Number : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address.flatNumber"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Building Name : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address.buildingName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>City : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address.city"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  

</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Controller Method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addBean.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addContactFromBean(@ModelAttribute("student1") @Valid ContactBean student1, BindingResult result){

    System.out.println("Inside addContactFromBean");

    if(result.hasErrors()){ // this binding result checks for error
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        System.out.println("Some error occured in input.");
        System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
        return model;
    }

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("viewStudent");

    System.out.println("Student Bean : "+student1.toString());
    model.addObject("student1", student1);

    System.out.println("View Name :->> "+model.getViewName());
    return model;
}
```

The Spring Bean:

```
package com.springTut;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class ContactBean {
**@NotEmpty
private String firstname;**
**@Size( min=6, max=16, message="Size.student1.lastname")**
**private String lastname;**
private String email;
private String dob;
private Long telephone;
private List<String> skillSet;
private AddressBean address;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ContactBean [firstname=" + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + ", telephone="
            + telephone + ", skillSet=" + skillSet + ", address=" + address + "--.]";
}
public String getDob() {
    return dob;
}
public void setDob(String dob) {
    this.dob = dob;
}
public List<String> getSkillSet() {
    return skillSet;
}
public void setSkillSet(List<String> skillSet) {
    this.skillSet = skillSet;
}
public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}
public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}
public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
public Long getTelephone() {
    return telephone;
}
public void setTelephone(Long telephone) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
}
public AddressBean getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(AddressBean address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Comment: ****CORRECTING THE QUESTION**form:error is not showing error messages in form:from tag. It shows error messages if the form:error tag is out of the form:form tag. I have printed the errors of the bnding result and it shows the errors as below but doesnt works in tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding and validation errors are registered in the model. The  tag retrieves these  errors from the model for display purposes. If the tag is nested inside a form:form tag the effective error key or path is the combination of the modelAttribute attribute in the form:form tag and the path you specify. In your case the modelAttribute is not explicit. Change your form as follows

```
<form:form method="post" action="/SampleTutorials/student/addBean.html" modelAttribute="student1">

      <label>Last Names</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><label>First Name</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstname"/></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Last Names</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lastname"/>
         <form:errors path="lastname"> </form:errors>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>DOB</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dob"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Email</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Telephone</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="telephone"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Skillset</label></td>
        <td>
            <select multiple name="skillSet">
              <option value="J2EE">J2EE</option>
              <option value="J2SE">J2SE</option>
              <option value="Spring">Spring</option>
              <option value="Hibernate">Hibernate</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Flat Number : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address.flatNumber"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Building Name : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address.buildingName"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>City : </label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="address.city"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Add Contact"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>  

</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the spring form properly for the model attribute object and the internal attributes i mean.

In your form

```
<form:form method="post" action="/SampleTutorials/student/addBean.html" attribute="student">

...
<td><form:input type="text" path="lastname"/>
     <form:errors path="lastname"> </form:errors>
</td>
...
```

Let me know if in this case also fails